# Rails multiple has_many relations through a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many, polymorphic-associations

I am wondering how I can handle the following situation:

`Page` has_many `Assets`

`Stylesheet` has_many `Assets`

`Javascript` has_many `Assets`

Now I want to be able to execute the following queries:

`Page.first.assets` # shows all assets (stylesheets and javascripts) for this page

`Page.first.assets.javascripts` # shows all javascript assets for this page (same for stylesheets)

`Javascript.first.pages` # shows all the pages which include this javascript (same for stylesheets)

I currently have this setup:

```
Assets:
  stylesheet_id
  javascript_id
  page_id

  belongs_to :stylesheet
  belongs_to :javascript
  belongs_to :page

  scope :stylesheets, where{ stylesheet_id != nil } ###
  scope :javascripts, where{ javascript_id != nil } # uses "squeel" gem

Pages:
  has_many :assets
  has_many :stylesheets, through: :assets
  has_many :javascripts, through: :assets

Stylesheets/Javascripts:
  content (text field)

  has_many :assets
  has_many :pages, through: :assets
```

**The problem with this is not that it doesn't work**

However, it feels that this isn't the right way, because I have three `*_id` fields in the `Assets` model. `javascript_id`, `stylesheet_id` and `page_id`. With every row, either `javascript_id` or `stylesheet_id` will be empty in this situation, which feels like a code smell to me.

Any suggestions how to handle this situation?

Comment: Polymorphic relationships to resque.

Comment: Care to elaborate or post it as an answer instead of a comment? I tried searching for Polymorphic examples, but somehow it seemed like what I was trying to do is actually the reversed of a polymorphic relationship, no? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Actually, looking at my code again, and looking at the rails guides, I am starting to see how this works. Thank you! If you put it as an answer I can mark it, or I'll just post the solution for others to find.

Comment: Better you put your code as answer once you get it working :)

Comment: Try [polymorphic association](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rubish Thank you for the help, together with other stackoverflow posts I now have the following working, but I still feel that I am either overcomplicating things or missing some key info, but at least it works (for the most part).

### models/theme.rb

```ruby
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible #none

   belongs_to :website
   has_many :pages
   has_many :assets, class_name: "ThemeAsset", dependent: :destroy

   has_many :styles, class_name: "AssetStyle", through: :assets, source: :assetable, source_type: "AssetStyle"
   has_many :scripts, class_name: "AssetScript", through: :assets, source: :assetable, source_type: "AssetScript"
 end
```

### models/theme_asset.rb

```ruby
class ThemeAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :assetable

  belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :theme
end
```

### models/asset_style.rb

```ruby
class AssetStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible #none

  has_many :assets, class_name: "ThemeAsset",  as: :assetable
end
```

### models/asset_script.rb

```ruby
class AssetScript < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible #none

  has_many :assets, class_name: "ThemeAsset",  as: :assetable
end
```

The following allows me to work with the different assets, but I don't know if it's the proper way to do this, becuase:

- `theme.assets` shows all `theme_asset` rows, with `assetable_id` and `assetable_type`
- I cound't find a default way to show only styles or scripts through `theme.assets.scripts`, but I guess I could use a `scope` for that, same as in my original question
- If I do `theme.styles.create` the style is saved, but no record is added to the `asset` table, meaning I can never find it through `theme.assets`.
- The only way for both records to be added is to use `theme.assets.create(assetable: theme.styles.new)` (simplified)

Is this the correct way, and if not, could anyone build on top of my solution? Thank you in advance.